# Issues Using Android LinearLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext, textview

I have a `LinearLayout`, containing one `EditText` and one `TextView`. My `ConsoleWindow` is running in a loop, and I would like to update the `TextView` in each Iteration.

The problem is that I may initialize the `EditText` only once (otherwise it is inaccessible) and also the `LinearLayout` may only be initialized once (otherwise it would remove the `EditText`).

I cannot put the `LinearLayout` and the `EditText` in an if-statement:

```
if (firstRun) {
     // initialize LinearLayout and EditText
     firstRun = false;
}
// TEXTVIEW
TextView tv = new TextView(getApplicationContext())
tv.setText(dataStringTot);
layout.addView(tv); // "Qualifier must be an Expression."
```

because the IDE Returns at `layout.addView(tv);` : "Qualifier must be an expression."

**My Code:**

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

getInetContent();
}

getInetContent() { // would be a thread
// getting data...

Bundle b = new Bundle();
b.putString("StringNMEA", NMEA);
Message m = mhandler.obtainMessage();
m.setData(b);
mhandler.sendMessage(m);
}


Handler handler = new Handler() {
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        String dataString = "";
        Bundle bundle = msg.getData();

        if (bundle.containsKey("display")) {
        ConsoleWindow(dataString);
        }
    }
}

private void ConsoleWindow(String dataString) {

            // LINEAR LAYOUT
            LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(this);
            setContentView(layout);
            layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
            layout.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#000000")); // black


            // EDITTEXT
            EditText et = new EditText(getApplicationContext());
            et.setHint("Enter Command");
            layout.addView(et);


            // TEXTVIEW
            TextView tv = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
            tv.setText(dataStringTot);
            layout.addView(tv);
            }
}
```

**My Code with if-statement:**

```
public boolean firstRun = true;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

getInetContent();
}

getInetContent() { // would be a thread
// getting data...

Bundle b = new Bundle();
b.putString("StringNMEA", NMEA);
Message m = mhandler.obtainMessage();
m.setData(b);
mhandler.sendMessage(m);
}


Handler handler = new Handler() {
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        String dataString = "";
        Bundle bundle = msg.getData();

        if (bundle.containsKey("display")) {
        ConsoleWindow(dataString);
        }
    }
}

private void ConsoleWindow(String dataString) {
       if (firstRun) {
            // initialize LinearLayout and EditText:
            // LINEAR LAYOUT
            LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(this);
            setContentView(layout);
            layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
            layout.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#000000")); // black


            // EDITTEXT
            EditText et = new EditText(getApplicationContext());
            et.setHint("Enter Command");
            layout.addView(et);
            firstRun = false;
        }


            // TEXTVIEW
            TextView tv = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
            tv.setText(dataStringTot);
            layout.addView(tv);
            }
}
```

How could I fix this Problem?

Comment: post the whole method

Comment: you can't call setContentView(layout) in each iteration.

Comment: i know, thats why I wanted to do an if-Statement (so it only sets contentview in the first run). but the Problem is the "qualifier must be an Expression"...

Comment: @Blackbelt I just added the whole method

Comment: Actually is the whole class. Still I can't find the `if(firstRun)` guard anywhere

Comment: sorry, totally forgot it. now it should fit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I imagine you want to update the colours/text of them each iteration.

You don't need to create a new View each time you want to modify it. Set up your layout, get the views and then pass those views into your loop.

```
LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(this);
EditText et = new EditText(this);
TextView tv = new TextView(this);
layout.addView(et);
layout.addView(tv);
setContentView(layout);

et.setHint("Enter Command");
tv.setText(dataStringTot);

startLoop(et, tv);

public void startLoop(final EditText et, final TextView tv) {
    ...
}
```

If your loop is a thread of some sort that isn't run on the main thread you might need to wrap it in a run on ui thread.

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() 
{
    public void run() 
    {
        Log.v("mainActivity", "test");
    }
});
```

Comment: I did what you suggested, but the IDE only lets me put `LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(this);` outside my function `ConsoleWindow()`. The problem then is that the app crashes with a NullPointerException in exactly that line. Any idea?